# Reproduce effects of Python 3.3 __qualname__ in earlier Pythons

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, cpython

[Python 3.3 added the `__qualname__` attribute](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3155/) which allows people to get the qualified name of a function (think module.submodule.class.function) or similar.

Is there a way to reproduce this attribute in Python 2.6 and 2.7?

Comment: You could get it for objects nested inside classes by exhaustively searching the tree of attributes, starting with objects in the global namespace.  I don't believe there would be a way to duplicate the `<locals>` indicator for functions defined inside other functions.

Comment: I am not quite clear on what you are suggesting, spider up globals() until you find locals() and your own identifier?

Comment: You can't get `locals()` without actually calling a function.  But you can spider through the `__dict__` of every object in `globals()`, then the `__dict__` of all those objects, etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've written a library that provides a `__qualname__` equivalent for older Python versions: https://github.com/wbolster/qualname

Comment: Congrats on scratching an itch I have had for a while!

Comment: [You also put it on PyPI!](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/qualname/) `pip install qualname`

Answer (score 2):

Judging by the arguments given in the PEP where `__qualname__` was proposed ([here](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3155/)), this seems to be impossible. There's `im_class`, which gives you the defining class of a module, but that's it.

Of course it's possible to just go through *all the things* from `globals()` until you find something that matches your `__name__`, but that can become arbitrarily complex, and is just plain horrible. If you indeed decide to do that, please also check if the two have the same identity (`a is b`), because any two things can have the same `__name__`.

Answer (score 1):

I've cooked up a hack that gets the qualified name for a (nested) class by using the inspect (for the class) and AST (for the source file) modules, and combining the results based on the line numbers. You can find it here:

https://gist.github.com/wbolster/d8ff5fe5ddca13391225