# How to reimplement Python's __qualname__ in Python 3.7? (with some minor adjustments)

Tags: python, python-3.x, introspection

The `__qualname__` attribute is useful to me because it contextualizes functions; however, it's difficult for me to use for my use case because:

1. `__qualname__` returns a string. For my usecase, I need references to the parent object(s).
2. `__qualname__` sometimes returns the `super` class instead of the referenced class. For example:

   ```py
   class Parent():

       def __init__(self):
           pass


   class Child(Parent):
       pass


   print(Child.__init__.__qualname__)  # Prints: "Parent.__init__"
   ```
3. The package I am developing needs to be robust, and the edge cases for `__qualname__` are not [documented](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3155/) as far as I can tell.

Outside of [parsing the Python file](https://github.com/wbolster/qualname/blob/master/qualname.py) with `ast`, can `__qualname__` be reimplemented in Python3 with inspection? How does Python implement `__qualname__`? In reimplementing the core functionality, I think I'll be able to adapt it for my use case.

---

**Prior Research:**

- PEP 3155: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3155/
- Python 2 `qualname` implementation: https://github.com/wbolster/qualname/blob/master/qualname.py
- Parsing `__qualname__` to get references: [Get defining class of unbound method object in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3589311/get-defining-class-of-unbound-method-object-in-python-3/25959545#25959545)
- Python 2 `__qualname__` stackoverflow: [Reproduce effects of Python 3.3 __qualname__ in earlier Pythons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26544078/reproduce-effects-of-python-3-3-qualname-in-earlier-pythons)

I was unable to find the qualname implementation in the Python source code.

Comment: Can you give a short glimpse in what you're trying to achieve using the `__qualname__` attribute ? Meaning which problem do you want to solve using `__qualname__` ? Maybe there are alternative approaches that come to peoples mind.

Comment: Why do you call `__qualname__` output in your example "unexpected"? Since child class doesn't override `__init__`, it get's it inherited from parent class. `__qualname__` returns the string path to method reference, which in this case will be parents `__init__`.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this :) 

@klaas I am looking to reconstruct the dotted path given a reference to function or method. For example, if provided a reference to `Child.__init__`, I'd like to be able to return a list consisting of `[Child, Child.__init__]`.

This is similar but more general than something like this: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3589311/get-defining-class-of-unbound-method-object-in-python-3/25959545#25959545

Comment: Thanks for getting clarification!

@ptyshevs The two functions `Child.__init__` and `Parent.__init__` are different, I think. For example,  `Child.__init__` can be decorated separately from `Parent.__init__`. Even so, they have the same `__qualname__`. I didn't expect that two methods could be uniquely decorated and have the same `__qualname__`.

Comment: @MichaelPetrochuk: But they're not different. They're literally the same object.

Comment: Sure, you could have applied separate decorators to `Child.__init__` and `Parent.__init__`, and if you had, you would probably have two different functions, but you didn't.

Comment: Also, "`__qualname__` returns a string instead of references." - well, yeah. It's a name. What did you want instead? I don't see a good alternative that would still preserve `__qualname__`'s functionality.

Comment: I am not here to argue about the design choices behind `__qualname__`. The implementation of `__qualname__` doesn't suit my application, and I need help to reimplement the functionality. In doing so, I'll be able to adjust it to the specification the application requires.

Comment: Okay, but what did you want instead? You haven't made that clear.

Comment: [Here's where CPython determines a function or class's `__qualname__`.](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.8.5/Python/compile.c#L679) It happens at compile time, and works off of parse tree information.

Comment: Like the question asks... I'm trying to: "Reimplement Python's `__qualname__` in Python 3.7". Can you help me with that?

In order to be helpful, I have adjusted the post to clarify my intentions and perspective. Sorry for the confusion, and thanks for your patience. I'm doing my best!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can accept an unconventional (or cumbersome) class creation using subclasses from a `BaseNode` class for every attribute

```
class A(BaseNode):
    class a(BaseNode):
        pass
    a = a()


class B(BaseNode):
    class a1(A):
        pass
    a1 = a1()

    class a2(A):
        pass
    a2 = a2()


class C(B):
    class c(BaseNode):
        pass
    c = c()
```

then every attribute knows his path name in the class hierarchy. (The class creation can be simplified by using `__init_subclass__()` or a decorator.)

```
c = C()
assert c._pathname      == 'C'
assert c.c._pathname    == 'C.c'
assert c.a1._pathname   == 'C.a1'
assert c.a1.a._pathname == 'C.a1.a'
assert c.a2._pathname   == 'C.a2'
assert c.a2.a._pathname == 'C.a2.a'
```

Every attribute instance is created by demand which you can see on the `print` outputs

```
*** <__main__.C object at 0x7fca81558190>  creates 'c' from <class '__main__.C.c'>
*** <__main__.C object at 0x7fca81558190>  creates 'a1' from <class '__main__.B.a1'>
*** <__main__.B.a1 object at 0x7fca8155b760>  creates 'a' from <class '__main__.A.a'>
*** <__main__.C object at 0x7fca81558190>  creates 'a2' from <class '__main__.B.a2'>
*** <__main__.B.a2 object at 0x7fca8155b490>  creates 'a' from <class '__main__.A.a'>
```

The `BaseNode` class uses `self._parent` for tracking the parent object (= instance of the parent class).

```
    class BaseNode:
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        self._parent = parent

    @property
    def _path(self):
        path = []
        obj = self
        while obj:
            path.append(obj)
            obj = obj._parent
        return path[::-1]

    @property
    def _pathname(self):
        return '.'.join(node.__class__.__name__ for node in self._path)

    def __get__(self, obj, cls=None):
        if obj is None:
            return self
        name = self.__class__.__name__
        try:
            inst = obj.__dict__[name]
        except KeyError:
            print(f'*** {obj}  creates {name!r} from {self.__class__}')
            inst = self.__class__(obj)
            obj.__dict__[name] = inst
        return inst
```

The descriptor method `__get__()` dynamically creates the attributes (= BaseNode instances) on demand.

BTW: Any comments or improvements for this approach are welcome :-)

Comment: The purpose was to have something that works for methods, though. Methods aren't instances of `BaseNode`, so they won't have any of this functionality. You can try to add functionality to make `BaseNode` instances work like methods, but it gets **really** messy, bug-prone, and cumbersome, as well as breaking all sorts of IDE help and introspection.

Answer (score 7):

You're not going to get what you want. You want `your_thing(Parent.__init__)` to say something about `Parent` and `your_thing(Child.__init__)` to say something about `Child`, but `Parent.__init__` and `Child.__init__` are the same exact object.

You've accessed that object two different ways, but Python keeps no record of that. Whatever you implement will only receive a function object, without the information you're looking for.

Even if you do some horrible stack inspection thing to look at the fact that the source code for `your_thing(Child.__init__)` says "Child" in it, that won't work for cases where the function gets stored in a variable or passed around through a few more layers of function calls. It'll only work, unreliably, for a fraction of cases where you don't need it because you already had the information you wanted when you were writing the code.

Comment: As mentioned earlier, the objective is to reimplement `__qualname__`.

Comment: @MichaelPetrochuk: The objective is to reimplement `__qualname__` *with adjustments*, one of which is impossible. (Adjustment 1 is pretty trivial, but adjustment 2 is not.) If it wasn't for the adjustments, you would just use `__qualname__`.